# Ionic 2/ Angular 2 => Use ionic 2 html tags inside angular 2 component

Tags: tags, angular, components, ionic2

I want to split a Ionic2 Page into smaller components. In addition I have created  Angular2 Components which I insert in the Ionic2 Page. See Code.
If I now use Ionic2 HTML tags in the Angular2 Componentes I get the

> No value accessor for '' "

error for my `<ion-textarea>` tag.

**Ionic Page:**

```
@Page({
  selector: 'game',
  directives: [QuestionComponent, AnswerComponent],
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/quiz/quiz.page.html',
  styles: [`

   `], 
)}
...
```

**Ionic Page HTML:**

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
<ion-title>Game: {{game.id}} -> Round {{round}}</ion-title>
```

```
<!-- Question Card -->
<question></question>

<!-- Answer Card -->
<answer></answer>
```

**Angular2 Component:**

```
import {Component}      from 'angular2/core'
import {Answer}             from "../../../models/answer";
import {AnswerService}      from "../../../services/answer.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'answer',
    providers: [AnswerService],
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/quiz/answer/answer.page.html',
    styles: [`

     `],
})
...
```

**Angular Component HTML:**

```
<ion-card>
<ion-card-content>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Answer</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="answerText">></ion-textarea>
        <button outline item-right (click)="submitAnswer(answerText)">
            Send
            <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Is it possible to use Ionic2 tag components in a Angular2 Component?
Or what is the best way to divided an Ionic 2 page into small components?

*EDIT

***Solution***

I have found a solution which solves my problem. 
Link to solution => [Using ion-input inside custom component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849428/using-ion-input-inside-custom-component)

To solve it you have to insert the Ionic 2 Directive in the Angular2 Komponetne .

**Fix Angular Component:**

```
import {Component}          from 'angular2/core'
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES}   from 'ionic-angular';

import {Answer}             from "../../../models/answer";
import {AnswerService}      from "../../../services/answer.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'answer',
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [AnswerService],
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/quiz/answer/answer.page.html',
    styles: [`

     `],
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ion-input inside custom component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849428/using-ion-input-inside-custom-component)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Ionic but this works for Polymer elements and might work here as well - add `ngDefaultControl`:

```
<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="answerText" ngDefaultControl></ion-textarea>
```

otherwise you'd probably need to implement a custom [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html) like mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6639#issuecomment-174703547

See also [ngModel: No value accessor for ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496514/ngmodel-no-value-accessor-for)

Comment: Yep, implementing `ControlValueAccessor` is the way to go here :)

Comment: Thanks ! Adding ngDefaultControl resolved the error. But the Ionic2 tagsdo not work correctly with this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the property `answerText` exists into the AnswerComponent class ?