# Ionic 3 iOS build --prod Not Working: Declarations of 2 Modules Error

Tags: cordova, build, ionic3, production

I have ruthlessly tried to build my Ionic 3 app for production using several different methods.

### Attempts

Firstly I imported `enableProdMode` from Angular and called `enableProdMode` in my `app.component.ts` constructor. In turn, I got a **blank screen** when I built the app.

I decided that this was an unnecessary step, as the [Ionic Framework documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) suggested that I simply run `ionic cordova build ios --prod` to get a production build. In turn, I got the following errors.

### Errors

After running the aforementioned line of code to build my app for production, I received this in the console output and my build was then terminated (condensed for legibility).

```
Type AvatarComponent in .../avatar.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in .../app.module.ts and AvatarComponentModule in .../avatar.module.ts! Please consider moving AvatarComponent in .../avatar.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in .../app.module.ts and AvatarComponentModule in .../avatar.module.ts.
```

Thus, I tried doing exactly what Cordova prompted me to do, so I removed my `avatar.module.ts` file and voila, the error was gone. To my dismay, this issue occurred for every single component in my project (keep in mind, every component was generated automatically through `ionic g component`). After repeating this process for every component, my app began loading with a **blank screen** just as it had done when I tried using `enableProdMode`.

### Misc. Details

```
cli packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.2

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.1
    Node              : v8.6.0
    npm               : 5.4.2 
    OS                : macOS Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

### Summary

I would like a way to mitigate the `Type ___ in ___/__.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules` issue, as well as an explanation as to why this occurs despite my usage of the pre-installed generation method.

Feel free to ask for clarification. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: As the error say, it is because you declare your component in 2 modules. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166922/4254681) to fix it. If you have any question please let me know

Comment: @Duannx I read your answer, but I do not want to centralize all components into one shared module and then import from `app.module.ts`. I've seen this answer before and I posted this question to seek an alternative solution to this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to delete the `.module.ts` (ngModule file) from each component and page folder generated by Ionic. Then, I made sure the components from my app were listed as `declarations` in my `app.module.ts` file. The app compiled perfectly in production.

Here is how my folder structure for a sample component or page looks like now:

```
/examplecomponent
    /examplecomponent.html
    /examplecomponent.scss
    /examplecomponent.ts
```

Additionally, here is how my `app.module.ts` file imports these components:

```
import { ExampleComponent } from '../components/examplecomponent/examplecomponent';

@NgModule({
      declarations: [
            ExampleComponent
      ],
      imports: [
            IonicModule.forRoot(App),
            CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
            ElasticModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
            MyApp,
            MainPage
      ],
      providers: [
            {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
            // All Injectable Classes Go Here
            Alert,
            Analytics,
            Auth,
            Background
      ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If your issue persists, see **Philip Brack**'s Solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation for 'is part of the declarations of 2 modules'

To explain the `ionic g` issue,  in ionic 3 they have started configuring your components to be lazy-loaded. this is why you are ending up with the .module.ts file. In my case I took a different approach, I actually included the module for the component in my app.module.ts

### share.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SharePage } from './share';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SharePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SharePage),
  ],
})
export class SharePageModule {}
```

### app.module.ts

```
// I removed other modules just look at how I encorporate the component "SharedPageModule"
import {SharePageModule} from "../pages/share/share.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ProjectPageModule,
    SharePageModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      preloadModules: true
    }),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    MomentModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    EmailComposer,
    File,
    Globalization,
    Keyboard,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ModelProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

### Resolving your issue

I don't get any issues building with `ionic cordova build ios --prod` or white screen of death at run-time so perhaps it would help to import the modules as I have.

I doubt that will resolve your white screen of death so I would suggest [debugging on your device or simulator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/developer-tips/).

Comment: Did what you suggested, but I am looking for an answer specific to components, since they are causing this issue. Also, here is my error output for my `button` component after following your instructions: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'button' is not a known element: 1. 
            If 'button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'button' 
            is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to 
            suppress this message.`

Comment: strange error. Have you tried option 2.  I remember needing to do that on one of my apps.  Cannot remember what for though at the moment.

Comment: I am starting to think this is a red herring.  Perhaps the issue is with one of your dependencies...

Comment: Progress! I deleted the `.module.ts` file from each component and kept the component imports in my `app.module.ts` file. I have a new error now, however, and it's caused by a set of `Injectable` helper classes I put in the `src/classes` folder I created. I am confused as to how these classes should be imported into `app.module.ts` since they are neither components nor modules.

Comment: See error: `Error: Cannot determine the module for class Alert in .../src/classes/alert.ts! Add Alert to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class Phone in.../src/classes/phone.ts! Add Phone to the NgModule to fix it.`... etc.

Comment: Those should show up in providers section of app.module.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157313/discussion-between-philip-brack-and-anthony-krivonos).